# What is the fastest way/library to calculate the rank of a matrix in C++

Tags: c++, windows, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix

What library computes the rank of a matrix the fastest? Or, is there any code out in the open that does this fairly rapidly?

I am using Eigen3 and it seems to be slower than Python's numpy rank function. I just need this one function to be fast, absolutely nothing else matters. If you suggest a package everything but this is irrelevant, including ease of use.

The matrices I am looking at tend to be  n by ( n choose 3) in size, the entries are 1 or 0....mostly 0's.

Thanks.

**Edit 1**: the rank is over R.

Comment: Do you care if the algorithm is randomized but always correct if it terminates, or even if it is randomized and has some chance to be wrong?

Comment: I do not follow. I care only about speed.

Comment: If you can tolerate having like .0001% chance of failure, according to this paper you should be able to do it in linear time in the size of your matrix, using their first result (on page 2) https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~lapchi/papers/matrix-rank.pdf edit: (3) result should do the same thing for you I guess, it might be harder to implement though, I'm not sure. The point is that if you have n by n choose 3 size, then the value `n^{w}` in the paper is negligible in these expressions because `w < 3`. Don't know how these do in practice but in theory I guess they are optimal.

Comment: @ChrisBeck you should post as answer...  even if OP doesn't like it others might

Comment: Can you tell us what are typical/maximal values of `n`? Is every row guaranteed to be non-0?

Comment: n ranges from 5 to 12. All columns have 3 1's, the rest 0's.

Comment: How are you computing the rank in Eigen? There are many different ways to do it, with different trade-offs between speed, precision, etc. (If you add the "eigen" tag and show your eigen code, you are more likely to get hints on how to improve that)

Comment: I am using:  Eigen::FullPivLU< Eigen::MatrixXd > lu_decomp(MATRIX);
 Rank = lu_decomp.rank();

Comment: Try another one from http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicLinearAlgebraDecompositions.html

Comment: @djechlin: the thing is its not really an answer of the quality that stackoverflow expects imo, hes sort of asking for a practical way to do something, all I did was glance at a paper.

Comment: @ReverseFlow: when you write this "n ranges from 5 to 12. All columns have 3 1's, the rest 0's.", you seem to know *alot* about the structure of this matrix, you might be able to just compute the rank in closed form using math, if you tell us the pattern of ones and zeros

Comment: Its complicated. There are thousands of them, like....thousands of them, for n=5 there are 36 and for n=7 they are in the 50K range already...I don't know a priori what they look like :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, [BLAS/LAPACK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAPACK) functions are frighteningly fast. [This link](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=818) suggests using the `GESVD` or `GESDD` functions to compute singular values. The number of non-zero singular values will be the matrix's rank.

LAPACK is [what numpy uses](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/1863).

In short, you can use the same LAPACK library calls. It will be difficult to outperform BLAS/LAPACK functions, unless sparsity and special structure allow more efficient approaches. If that's true, you may want to check around for alternative libraries implementing sparse SVD solvers.

Note also there are multiple BLAS/LAPACK implementations.

#### Update

[This post](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/1863) seems to argue that LU decomposition is unreliable for calculating rank. Better to do SVD. You may want to see how fast that eigen call is before going through all the hassle of using BLAS/LAPACK (I've just never used eigen).

Comment: I strongly suspect that for the very special case of a sparse matrix of 0s and 1s, it should be possible to write homebrew code that does it much faster than by treating the matrix as a regular matrix without regards to its content.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist Yeah, depends on how sparse, what `n` is, and if there's any special structure to the sparsity. I still wouldn't go total home brew as sparse SVD is an active research area. Quick google searches turns up some packages/libraries.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist good point though, a sparse solver might be the way to go.

Comment: I was more focusing on the fact that the elements have specific values of 0 or 1; I _think_ it shouldn't be necessary to carry out any multiplications at all to figure out the _rank_. You just need to compare elementwise the rows "somehow", and use their elementwise inequalities to find a subset of `k` out of `n` linearly independent rows.

Comment: He can try some sparse options without changing library http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialSparse.html (for instance http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SparseQR.html )